# Diagnosing high CPU usage by systemd on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

Not sure *exactly* when this started, but in the last few days I think. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a server, and noticed its load was incredibly high. It's almost doing nothing (I've installed 2 KVM guests, but only 1 is running right now). It has 24 logical cores, and the load is 12 constantly after reboot. Starting / stopping the KVM guests makes no difference

Snapshot of `htop`:

[image: htop]

Running `systemd-cgtop` shows little more:

[image: systemd-cgtop]

Running strace on that process from `htop` shows mostly lines that look like:

```
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 345, NULL, 8)  = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 154, NULL, 8)  = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 500, NULL, 8)  = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 345, NULL, 8)  = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 155, NULL, 8)  = 0
```

with a very occasional mix of:

```
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 160, NULL, 8)  = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=13, u64=13}}], 1024, 500, NULL, 8) = 1
read(13, "{\"id\":90,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\""..., 2048) = 64
futex(0xa15408, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
futex(0xa153a0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1)  = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}], 1024, 164, NULL, 8) = 1
read(9, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 1024)       = 8
epoll_pwait(4, [], 1024, 164, NULL, 8)  = 0
```

If I just kill that process, everything *appears* to go back to normal—certainly load wise, and the KVM guests seem unaffected.

Is there anything else I can try to figure out what the underlying cause is?

Other info—please ask for whatever else would be useful:

```
# dpkg -l systemd
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-===================================================
ii  systemd                 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64            system and service manager

# apt list --installed | grep systemd
libnss-systemd/bionic-updates,now 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64 [installed]
libpam-systemd/bionic-updates,now 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64 [installed]
libsystemd0/bionic-updates,now 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64 [installed]
python3-systemd/bionic,now 234-1build1 amd64 [installed]
systemd/bionic-updates,now 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64 [installed]
systemd-sysv/bionic-updates,now 237-3ubuntu10.40 amd64 [installed]
```

Output of `perf top --pid=$(pgrep systemd -d,)`:

```
Samples: 4M of event 'cycles:ppp', Event count (approx.): 455698006733
Overhead  Shared Object             Symbol
   4.07%  systemd                   [.] hashAes1Rx4<false>
   2.90%  systemd                   [.] fillAes1Rx4<false>
   0.44%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::generateProgramPrologue
   0.32%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9795105
   0.28%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97c5105
   0.28%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97b5105
   0.28%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9795129
   0.28%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97a5105
   0.27%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97e5105
   0.27%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97d5105
   0.25%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97c5129
   0.25%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97b5129
   0.25%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97d5129
   0.25%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97e5129
   0.25%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97a5129
   0.24%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9845129
   0.24%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9825129
   0.24%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9815129
   0.24%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9835129
   0.24%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9845105
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9805129
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9835105
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97f5129
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9825105
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9815105
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe97f5105
   0.23%  perf-1597.map             [.] 0x00007f4fe9805105
   0.16%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_CBRANCH
   0.09%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_ISTORE
   0.08%  systemd                   [.] fillAes4Rx4<false>
   0.08%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_FMUL_R
   0.05%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_IADD_RS
   0.05%  systemd                   [.] randomx_reciprocal_fast
   0.05%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_IMUL_R
   0.05%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_ISUB_R
   0.04%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_IXOR_R
   0.04%  systemd                   [.] randomx::JitCompilerX86::h_FSUB_R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would help to get some idea what exactly those PIDs are doing. strace is not a complete picture, as the system calls sampled may not be relevant to its performance.

Try profiling. Install debug symbols to get function names rather than meaningless numbers.  A thing doing most of the on CPU time should dominate samples, but filter to systemd named PIDs anyway:

```
perf top --pid=$(pgrep systemd -d,)
```

Top few functions will advise our suggestions, as well as provide something to send through your other OS support channels.

Also, consider testing whether these still are busy when running rescue.target. Rescue shell is much simpler, and not having the problem would rule out very early init.

---

Specifics of installing debug symbols generally mean reading [Ubuntu's wiki on symbols](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages), installing a http://ddebs.ubuntu.com  repo, and finding your favorite way to find the dbgsym packages. Starting with `systemd-dbgsym` as presumably that covers the `systemd` binary.  In addition, I am partial to the wiki's suggestion of

```
apt install debian-goodies
find-dbgsym-packages [core_path|running_pid|binary_path]
```

Success means looking at `perf top` or `gdb` stack traces, finding a familiar function name, and using that to investigate further.

hashAes1Rx4 seems to be an AES hash primitive. Searching GitHub for code with it leads to various crypto code, but nothing directly tied to systemd.

But wait, `randomx::JitCompilerX86` is C++ code from a [proof of work project](https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/blob/master/src/jit_compiler_x86.cpp). sytsemd is C. The [Monero cryptocurrency uses AES](https://monerodocs.org/proof-of-work/cryptonight/) in its proof of work. **I suspect this host is doing crypto mining.** Very likely from misuse or compromise.

I am not a security person, so you will want to find proof via indicators of compromise. And a full response, if infected.

However, this would explain some puzzling behavior. systemd isn't written in C++. And doesn't have a use case for doing that much AES, not overwhelming your actual compute workloads. Work done by units would appear in their cgroups. But pretending to be the systemd binary would be a good disguise for malware.

---

No shortcut for doing this type of investigation, unfortunately. Suspicion that doesn't look like what it should do, hunting down function names in open source, then remembering that crypto mining is a thing at the moment.

Comment: Updated question with output of `perf`. Note that `pgrep systemd -d,` does _not_ give the same pids that show as 100% CPU in `htop`. Unfortunately this server is being used, so I have to look for windows when I can tinker with it. I'll look to get debug symbols and rescue shell info. Many thanks.

Comment: Then install debug symbols and  do `perf top` again, without the pid filter (which is less useful than I thought it would be). You filtered 4 million on CPU events out of 4,500 million total, which doesn't really capture a consume all your CPU thing.

Comment: From what's there already, can you recommend which debug symbols to install? From what I've read, they seem to be associated with specific services. systemd-dbg is available for 16.04, but not for 18.04 as far as I can tell.

Comment: See edit for my theory...

Comment: Thanks—I'd tried `find-dbgsym-packages /bin/systemd` before posting my previous comment, but it didn't find anything. I just ran it again to get the exact message, and thought I'd try it on one of the pids. Again it didn't find anything, but in the list of "couldn't find" messages it highlighted a peculiar looking path to a library that did indeed lead to a cryptominer. So, thanks for all the pointers and your theory looks proven correct :).